# Client side Email Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

what regular expressions are used for email validation can you help me out

```
$("Textbox").rules("add", { regularExpression: "^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$" })
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: @coolguy catchme  didn't you try by typing 'Client side Email Validation  in jquery'  in google.com   before posting the question here . please try your self first before asking a question  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this...

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
```

Comment: Just be prepared to handle complaints from people whose email address is valid according to the standard but invalid according to this regex.

Comment: @query master That regex would validate an email like xyz@.co.og as true. Can we have a period after @? Also og is not a valid domain which would be validated true

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This regex would work.

`^([a-zA-Z])([\w-.]*)@([\w]+)([\w-.])*\.(aero|asia|be|biz|com.ar|ca|co|co.in|co.jp|co.kr|co.sg|com|com.ar|com.mx|com.sg|com.ph|co.uk|coop|de|edu|es|fr|gov|in|info|it|jobs|ltd|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|net.mx|org|ru|us)+$`